# Pandas how do I compare columns for equality in a dataframe that have the same name except for a suffix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have a dataframe that has a lot of columns in the following format:

| id | col1_df1 | col2_df1 | col3_df1 | col1_df2 | col2_df2 | col3_df2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | num | num | num | num | num | num |
| A2 | num | num | num | num | num | num |
| A3 | num | num | num | num | num | num |
| A4 | num | num | num | num | num | num |
| A5 | num | num | num | num | num | num |

I need to compare the columns with the same name before the prefix. That is, I need to compare `col1_df1` with `col1_df2`, `col2_df1` with `col2_df2`, and so on. I need to check the percentage of equality in each "repeated" column (in each col1, in each col2, and so on). I can't do it manually because there are a lot of columns.

Is there a way to do that using Pandas functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Kindly provide sample data with expected output dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
(df.groupby(lambda col: col.rpartition("_")[0], axis="columns")
   .diff().dropna(how="all", axis="columns")
   .eq(0).sum()
   .div(len(df)).mul(100)
   .rename(lambda idx: idx.rpartition("_")[0]))
```

- group the dataframe over columns' names before the *last* "_"
- take the difference of each group within itself

  - since there's nothing left to first columns of each group, they will be NaNs, so drop them
- check where differences are equal to 0, i.e., repetition: sum gives the count
- then percentify it
- lastly obtain the group names (before the last _) for the end result

to get something like (for some random data)

```py
col1    40.0
col2     0.0
col3    33.3
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi Mustafa, thanks! That seems like a very good way to do it. There's only one thing though. My column names also have other "_" in them. They are more like "thisis_acolumn_df1"

Comment: hi @AldanaBRZ. In that case, we can `rpartition("_")[0]`, i.e., changing partition to *r*ight partition, which will look for the underscore from the end of the string, and then take the left of it. Originally, it was looking for _ from left, and then taking the left of it.

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly. I was inconsistently using split in the last renaming phase, so I changed it to rpartition as well. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are already some reasonable answers, I'll take a guess and give a slightly different answer just in case it is useful.

Based on your column names it seems you are getting this dataframe from two dataframes where both have columns like: `col1`, `col2`, etc.  If that's the case, I would take a step back and do it like this:

```py
In [33]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4, size=(5, 3)),
    ...:       columns=[f"col1", "col2", "col3"],
    ...:       index=["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"])

In [34]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4, size=(5, 3)),
    ...:       columns=[f"col1", "col2", "col3"],
    ...:       index=["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"])

In [35]: df1
Out[35]: 
    col1  col2  col3
A1     0     0     1
A2     3     1     0
A3     0     2     3
A4     1     1     0
A5     3     0     1

In [36]: df2 
Out[36]: 
    col1  col2  col3
A1     1     2     3
A2     3     2     2
A3     3     0     3
A4     0     3     2
A5     2     0     1

In [37]: df2 == df1
Out[37]: 
     col1   col2   col3
A1  False  False  False
A2   True  False  False
A3  False  False   True
A4  False  False  False
A5  False   True   True

In [38]: res = df2 == df1

In [39]: res.sum(axis=0)
Out[39]: 
col1    1
col2    1
col3    2
dtype: int64
```

To get the above as percentage, you could do this:

```py
In [40]: res.sum(axis=0) / len(res) * 100
Out[40]: 
col1    20.0
col2    20.0
col3    40.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

For instance let's say we have the following dataframe :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'],
                   'col1_df1': [11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
                   'col2_df1': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                   'col3_df1': [9, 11, 9, 11, 9],
                   'col1_df2': [8, 11, 7, 10, 6],
                   'col2_df2': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
                   'col3_df2': [6, 11, 6, 11, 6],
                   })
```

**Visualization :**

```
   ID  col1_df1  col2_df1  col3_df1  col1_df2  col2_df2  col3_df2
0  A1        11        10         9         8         7         6
1  A2        11        11        11        11         8        11
2  A3        11        12         9         7         9         6
3  A4        11        13        11        10        10        11
4  A5        11        14         9         6        11         6
```

**Comparison with using of the following script :**

```py
r = (df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1)
     .diff(axis=1)
     .dropna(how='all', axis=1) 
     .rename(columns = {'col1_df2':'diff1', 'col2_df2':'diff2', 'col3_df2':'diff3'}, inplace = False))
```

And then `r` is :

```
   diff1  diff2  diff3
0     -3     -3     -3
1      0     -3      0
2     -4     -3     -3
3     -1     -3      0
4     -5     -3     -3
```

In `r`, 0 represents equality.

In `r` column named `diff1` (comparison between `col1_df1` and `col1_df2`), we get perc of 0 as follows :

```py
perc = float(eval('{0}/{1}'.format(r['diff1'].value_counts()[0], len(r['diff1']))))

print(per)
# 0.2 (ie 1 out of 5)
```

**Complete proposed script :**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'],
                   'col1_df1': [11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
                   'col2_df1': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                   'col3_df1': [9, 11, 9, 11, 9],
                   'col1_df2': [8, 11, 7, 10, 6],
                   'col2_df2': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
                   'col3_df2': [6, 11, 6, 11, 6],
                   })

r = (df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1)
     .diff(axis=1)
     .dropna(how='all', axis=1) 
     .rename(columns = {'col1_df2':'diff1', 'col2_df2':'diff2', 'col3_df2':'diff3'}, inplace = False))

 
perc = float(eval('{0}/{1}'.format(r['diff1'].value_counts()[0], len(r['diff1']))))

print(per)
# 0.2 (ie 1 out of 5)
```